# Initializing a Hash Table in C memory leak

Tags: c, hashtable, valgrind

The following code is giving segmentation fault. Where in the memory allocation did I wrongly allocate... There is a memory leak according to valgrind.
What does "invalid size of 8 mean"?

Any help much appreciated. Thanks

```
// Represents a node in a hash table

typedef struct node {
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
} node;

// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 26;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// If loaded
bool loaded = false;

void init_table() {
    table = malloc(sizeof(node) * N);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < N; i++) {
        table[i]->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

Valgrind is spitting this out:

[image]

Comment: `table` is a `node *` array. No need to call `table = malloc(sizeof(node) * N);`

Comment: Given the definition: `node *table[N];`, the code `table = malloc(sizeof(node) * N);` isn't even valid C, so it can't compile, run , and thus cannot leak anything. How about we address that *first*. A proper [mcve] that actually exhibits your *real* code would probably be highly illuminating.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp so should I do table[i] = malloc(sizeof(node)); for every i from 0 to N

Comment: @WhozCraig Ok, I will see into it

Comment: You call `malloc` when you add to the hash table. First calculate the hash (which should be some number >=0 and <N). Then `malloc` a new `node`. Then link that to the node list at the correct hash index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- `table` is defined as an array of `N` pointers to `node` structures. The line `table = malloc(sizeof(node) * N);` should not even compile. Your screenshot cannot possibly be produced by the posted code.
- As a matter of fact, in C, unlike C++, `const unsigned int N = 26;` does not define `N` as a compile time constant so `node *table[N];` is an invalid definition at global scope and would define a variable length array (VLA) at local scope. Your compiler seems to accept extensions borrowed from C++ or might even compile the code as C++. Define `N` as a macro or an `enum` value to make it a constant expression.
- the loop dereferences the elements in `table` as `table[i]->next = NULL;` but the array contains null pointers: dereferencing them causes undefined behavior.
- you should instead initialize the elements of `table` to `NULL`.

Here is a modified version:

```
// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node {
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
} node;

// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
enum { N = 26 };

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// If loaded
bool loaded = false;

void init_table(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        table[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```